# count and group data from 2 column on single table

Tags: sql, count, group-by

i have a problem when counting and grouping data from 2 column on single table.

**My table structure:**
id, price, user_1, user_2

**Data sample:**

```
001 500 bergkamp cech<br>
002 100 cech ljungberg<br>
003 200 viera henry<br>
004 300 bergkamp pires<br>
005 200 lauren bergkamp<br>
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT                          
user_1,user_2,            
count(user_1) as total1, 
count(user_2) as total2 
FROM                            
sales
group by user_1 and user_2
```

results with not what i want, 
**I want the output like this:**

```
bergkamp    3<br>
henry       1<br>
cech        2<br>
ljungberg   1<br>
lauren      1<br>
pires       1<br>
viera       1<br>
```

Any help will be so appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both user columns into one with a UNION. Then group by that temp table result and count the names

```
select user_name, count(*)
from
(
    SELECT user_1 as user_name FROM sales
    union all 
    SELECT user_2 FROM sales
) tmp
group by user_name
```

Comment: POOF! IT WORKS like a magic sir @juergen-d, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT t.user, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT user_1 AS user
    FROM sales
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_2
    FROM sales
) t
GROUP BY t.user
```